# how to change password in my login and register page?

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdb

I have this code login.jsp and registration.jsp
these jsps let me log in and register successfully and data will be saved it mysql database.
Now, the next thing to do is on how to change password.
Can you guys help me with the change password thing?
here is my database

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `first_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `uname` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `regdate` date NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

login.jsp

```
    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    String userid = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    rs = st.executeQuery("select * from members where uname='" + userid + "' and pass='" + pwd + "'");
    if (rs.next()) {
        session.setAttribute("userid", userid);
        //out.println("welcome " + userid);
        //out.println("<a href='logout.jsp'>Log out</a>");
        response.sendRedirect("success.jsp");
    } else {
        out.println("Invalid password <a href='index.jsp'>try again</a>");
    }
%>
```

registration.jsp

```
    <%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%
    String user = request.getParameter("uname");    
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
    String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    int i = st.executeUpdate("insert into members(first_name, last_name, email, uname, pass, regdate) values ('" + fname + "','" + lname + "','" + email + "','" + user + "','" + pwd + "', CURDATE())");
    if (i > 0) {
        //session.setAttribute("userid", user);
        response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
       // out.print("Registration Successfull!"+"<a href='index.jsp'>Go to Login</a>");
    } else {
        response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
    }
%>
```

EDIT here is my change.jsp i dont know if it is correct.

change.jsp

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%   
    String userid = request.getParameter("uname"); 
    String pwd = request.getParameter("pass");
    String chg = request.getParameter("change");
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/users",
            "root", "");
    Statement st = con.createStatement();
    ResultSet rs;
    st.executeUpdate("update members set chg='" + pwd + "' where uname='" + userid + "'");




%>
```

help me thanks!

Comment: Lets close this question.  Never never put this type of connection it JSP even as homework.

Comment: im sorry im just a beginner in jdbc

Comment: This is like asking for a tutorial. This question should be closed IMO.

Comment: nope i added a code. and i am asking what is wrong with it.

Comment: Please remove this code from the JSP. You are treading on very dangerous grounds. This is Bad Practice to put Connection in the JSP or any other jave code snipplets.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need an UPDATE sql to change the password.

```
update members set pass=? where uname=?
```

Please note that your code is currently vulnerable to SQL injection.

In your new code, you need to change

```
st.executeUpdate("update members set chg='" + pwd + "' where uname='" + userid + "'");
```

to

```
st.executeUpdate("update members set pwd='" + pwd + "' where uname='" + userid + "'");
```

Comment: Upvoted pointless unexplained downvote.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues with your existing approach, but let's start with the most basic.
It is unconscionable to store raw user passwords. You **should** [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) and [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function) them (what if someone reads your database)?

Next, you should **not** mix your presentation and business logic. The fact that you shouldn't do so in a JSP scriptlet is almost immaterial once you grasp this point. This is where you generally start to learn about design patterns - I strongly urge you to look at [Model-view-controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model-view-controller),

[image: Model-View-Controller UML from Wikipedia]

Finally, you should sanitize your user inputs ([PreparedStatement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html) with bind variables or use [StringEscapeUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html)). Otherwise, you're vulnerable to SQL [injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).

Comment: "You must salt and hash them." I don't think this is a production environment, something tells me, just a suspicion...

Comment: @jeremyjjbrown I edited to say *should*, but OP **really** *should*.

Answer (score -1):

your sql cannot be

```
"update members set chg='" + pwd + "' where uname='" + userid + "'"
```

if the password field in your table is

```
`pass` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
```

so your SQL should be

```
"update members set pass='" + pwd + "' where uname='" + userid + "'"
```

about sql injection, I think it's important for you to know that if the user enter a userid or pwd that contain one ', it will be enough to break your query.

that's why you should prefer using PreparedStatement (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of Statement

Comment: my password didnt change its still the same :(

Comment: it added a info where all are null except the password.

Comment: how are you passing the parameters uname and pass? via GET?

Comment: You shouldn't be recommending building SQL statements like this. Use of a PreparedStatement with arguments('?') is indicated.

Comment: @EJP I am already saying that he/she should use PreparedStatement instead, haven't you read the complete answer?

Comment: @user3236746 how are you calling your JSP? how are you SENDING the parameters, not how are you RECEIVING the parameters?

Comment: how about posting this code too?